# Trying to insert a selected row from db into a newtable

Tags: php

AM working on a registration form part of the form contain data that was fetched direct from my db, am finding it difficult inserting same data into a new table in sql db.

Am working with apache 2.4.23 and php 7.0

Here is the code

```
       <div class="form-group">
// Fetching data from db using select                                           

       <?php 
        $query= "SELECT * FROM class";
        $stmt=$conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result1=$stmt->get_result();
                                        ?>

       <label>CLASS</label>
       <select class="form-control">
       <option>Select Class</option>

    // i used while loop to fetch the row

      <?php while($row=$result1->fetch_assoc()){ ?>

    //This is where am having issues inserting the data to db
      <option value="clasname"><?= $row['clasname']; ?></option>
      <?php }?>
      </select>
     </div>
```

// Here is the insert part of the code

```
if(isset($_POST['add'])){

    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $reg_no=$_POST['reg_no'];
    $gender=$_POST['gender'];
    $class=$_POST['class'];
    $section=$_POST['section'];

    $photo=$_FILES['image']['name'];
    $upload="uploads/".$photo;

    $query="INSERT INTO add_student(fname,lname,reg_no,gender,class,section,photo)VALUES('$fname','$lname','$reg_no','$gender','$class','$section','$upload')";
    $stmt=$conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $fname,$lname,$reg_no,$gender,$class,$section,$upload);
    $stmt->execute();
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $upload);

    header('location:viewstudent.php');
    $_SESSION['response']="Succesfully inserted to the Database!";
    $_SESSION['res_type']="Success";

}
```

i expected it to be inserted to the db, no error messages other form data was saved successfully except the selected row

Comment: Your code is only performing a Select and displaying what you read from the Database table called class. It does not show anything related to inserting data into a database table. If you need help on that part of it you will need to show the code where you are performing the insert.

Comment: Here is the insert code

Comment: `<select class="form-control">` is missing a `name` attribute

Comment: Have you read up on how to use prepared statements? You should! Look at your insert query. Why does it have variable names in it?

Comment: It should be `VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`

Comment: Why do all your options have the same `value="classname"` instead of getting the value from the database?

Comment: Was Trying to name the options so as to be able to insert it to th db

Comment: You have to leave the `?` instead of variable names, so that you can then bind the parameters to the query and send it as you did in `bind_param`.